# Make some letters or numbers at the right hand side of document

Tags: horizontal-alignment

To shift letters or digits to the right hand side of the document, I use `\hfill` but when a sentence used up the line, the `\hfill` will move whatever you want to appear on the right to the next line and appear on the left.

Is it possible to make `\hfill` move lets say "NOTE" to the right even after the sentence used up the line and this "NOTE" appear on the next line not on the left but on the right?

Comment: `\hspace*{\fill}` will do what you ask but you shouldn't normally need to have such spacing in the document, perhaps `\begin{flushleft}` is what you want?

Comment: Tried \hfill\parbox{1cm}{[4]}, but not working. I am typing up some documents and want to show a marks for the question but somehow the mark will appear next line left hand side while my sentence used up the line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle (+1) Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`\hspace*{\fill}` will do what you ask but you shouldn't normally need to have such spacing in the document, perhaps

```
\begin{flushleft}
10
\end{flushleft}
```

is what you want?

Or perhaps for the usecase mentioned in comments moving into the margin might be better than flush left within the text block:

```
\marginpar{10}
```